# Difference between 2 files

Tags: c

I tried to find difference between two files:

```
Car
Wine
Man
```

```
Nobody
Car
Shoes
Cookies
```

I want the program to show the words that are in the first file, but not the second, like this:

```
Wine
Man
```

Here's what I tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define STORE 300
void file1(char*line,char*line1){
    if(strcmp(line,line1)<0){
        printf("%s",line);
    }
}
int main(){
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    fp1=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("file2.txt","r");
    char buff[STORE], buff1[STORE];
    while(fgets(buff,STORE,fp1)!=NULL){
        while(fgets(buff1,STORE,fp2)!=NULL){
            file1(buff,buff1);
        }
        rewind(fp2);
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Car
Car
Car
ManMan
```

Why don't I get the output I was expecting?

Comment: why `<0`? why not `!=0`?

Comment: you have a function called "file1".  Does it file stuff?  What does it file?  Where does it file it to?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run `diff`?

Comment: Also your program runs in `O( left * right )` time which is very suboptimal. I suggest you read up on `O(1)` lookup using hashtables, or at least binary-search in a sorted list.

Comment: @Dai maybe that's useful, but not really relevant to the language tag here, IMHO. :)

Comment: I don't know what I thought when I put <0,but  with != my result still show me Car...  It should not happen.

Comment: If you found my edit unhelpful, please say why - I thought it solved some actual problems with your formatting, and I'd like to know why you reverted it.

Comment: @TobySpeight I thought that I accepted your edit.

Comment: No, you reverted back to revision 1.  To accept the edit, you don't need to do anything.  I've re-rollbacked to revision 3 (which you can now see by following the [`edited` link](/posts/41107171/revisions) under your post.  Don't worry too much - we can see you're new here, and we want to help!

Comment: Thank you, was a mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background:

Here's what your program is doing in English.

```
Car is alphabetically before Nobody, so print it.
Car is NOT before Car, so do NOT print it.
Car is before Shoes -> print
Car is before Cookies -> print
Wine is NOT before Nobody (or anything) -> do NOT print
Man is before Nobody -> print
Man is NOT before Car -> do NOT print
Man is before Shoes -> print
Man is NOT before Cookies -> do NOT print
```

And thus, your result:
Car, car, car, man, man

Step 1:
your strcmp() call needs to be != 0 instead of <0.
The reason you never print 'wine' is because strcmp("wine", "nobody") is > 0, so it does not print Wine (ever)

Step 2: The void file1() function can return 1 if match, or 0 if no match, sum these up and only print the line if the sum is 0.   This is very inefficient, but will... get the job done.

Step 3 (maybe?) Are you missing a new line at the end of the last "Man" or something causing it to print ManMan?

```
int file1(char*line,char*line1){
   if(strcmp(line,line1)!=0)  /* note correct comparison */
       return 0;
   else
       return 1;
}

...

int match = 0;
while(fgets(buff,STORE,fp1)!=NULL){
    match = 0;
    while(fgets(buff1,STORE,fp2)!=NULL){
        match += file1(buff,buff1);
    }
    if (match == 0) { /* it never matched so print it */
        printf("%s", buff);
    }
    rewind(fp2);
}
```

Comment: And I was wondering why my program don't show Wine... I do not pay attention. If only exchange <0 with !=0 my result will not same as in your program, can you tell me why?

Comment: You need to make both changes (Step 1 and Step 2).  The first error (step 1) is that it is only printing items that occur prior.  The second error is a logic error when you print each line from list 1 EVERY time it doesn't match a line from the list 2.  I've edited my answer to illustrate what your program is actually doing.